How can I resolve this Error in GSAP (Invalid registerPlugin())?
gsap-core.js:89 Invalid property scrollTrigger set to .btn-description Missing plugin? gsap.registerPlugin()
it has been running in the localhost but It not works in production, how can i solve that???
enter image description here
how to resolve this

Show the code around where you call gsap.registerPlugin. But at a guess, the path to the plugin code is different on local than on prod.. maybe.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
